# SQL : Choose three stock tickers which have complete data between 2012 and 2017 in the Quandl Wiki data set

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I have a `custom_calendar` table like this:

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CokU.jpg "custom calendar image"

And I have a stocks market table ( `v_eod_quotes_2012_2017` ) which looks like this:

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9biu.jpg "v_eod_quotes_2012_2017"

As I mention in the question, I need to find out which three stock market symbols has complete data i.e data for every day in between 2012 and 2017.

I have the below query which I'm unsure of, because it is only returning me one row which is wrong. I wanted to first correct this query and get some data so that I can choose three ticker symbols. can anybody please help me correcting this query.

```
SELECT ticker, count(*)::real/
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM custom_calendar
        WHERE trading=1 AND
              date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
       )::real as pct_complete
FROM v_eod_quotes_2012_2017
GROUP BY ticker
HAVING count(*)::real/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM custom_calendar WHERE trading=1 AND date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2017-12-31')::real>=1.00
ORDER BY pct_complete DESC;
```

Output expected is more number of rows while I'm getting just one row for this query.

[3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySdYs.jpg " result"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm intrigued that LVFN has a value >1. Does that mean it traded on days the market was closed? Perhaps as an experiment instead of dividing real numbers you could try integer values of `count(*)` and the subquery as the fields, and change the `HAVING` clause to comparing `count(*)` is `>=` the subquery (without the `>= 1.0`). Other than perhaps some issue with the binary representation of real numbers being slightly inexact I can't see anything wrong with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you are getting even one row.  Your problem is that there is no connection between the quotes and the `custom_calendar`, so you are not counting the range between the two dates.

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT q.ticker, COUNT(*)
FROM v_eod_quotes_2012_2017 q JOIN
     custom_calendar cc
     ON q.date = cc.date
WHERE cc.trading = 1 AND
      cc.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY q.ticker
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM custom_calendar cc
                   WHERE cc.trading = 1 AND
                         cc.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2017-12-31')
                  );
```

The ratio is not helpful, because it should always be 1.

EDIT:

If the above generates zero rows, it is because no rows match.  Instead, get the most traded stocks using:

```
SELECT q.ticker, COUNT(*)
FROM v_eod_quotes_2012_2017 q JOIN
     custom_calendar cc
     ON q.date = cc.date
WHERE cc.trading = 1 AND
      cc.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY q.ticker
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```